# How to rescue by passing a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have defined my own method `authorize_user` in one of my controllers, as:

```
    def authorize_user
      if !((current_user.has_role? :admin, @operator) || (current_user.has_role? :super_admin))
        raise CanCan::AccessDenied
      end
    end
```

I want to rescue from the CanCan exception (or any other exception for that matter). I have used Rolify in my app. How do I rescue and redirect to the `root_url` of my app with a custom message?

I have tried the following options, but none of them worked:

Try 1:

```
rescue CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
end
```

Error in this case: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting '('`

Try 2:

```
rescue CanCan::AccessDenied
  redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Unauthorized Access"
```

Error in this case: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action`

How do I solve this issue?

---

This is my controller code:

```
class CabsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cab, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :authorize_user

 # Some basic CRUD actions

 private

    def set_cab
      @cab = Cab.find(params[:id])
      @operator = Operator.find(params[:operator_id])
    end


    def cab_params
      params.require(:cab).permit(:category, :number)
    end

    def authorize_user
      if !((current_user.has_role? :admin, @operator) || (current_user.has_role? :super_admin))
        raise CanCan::AccessDenied
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could try the [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) method.

For example, your `ApplicationController`, would look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :not_authorized

  #other stuff      

  private
  def not_authorized
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Unauthorized Access"
  end
end
```

---

Since the question was updated with more code, here is additional information:

Some suggestions:

- Make the `:authorize_user` a `before_action` as well. That way you don't need to worry about code running in the action even when the user was not allowed to do stuff.
- You might also need to add the same `:only` option as for the `:set_cab` since you use the `@operator` instance variable.
- Last, a personal code style preference is that I would have changed the `if !` to `unless` to increase reading flow.

Comment: Tried this also, again showing this error: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. How to get out of this?

Comment: Ok, then you'll probably need the `and return` as in the other answer.

Comment: Do you think you could update your question with the controller code as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some comments, does it seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `redirect_to(...) and return`.

Comment: Can you provide the complete answer please? My code doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with *Jakob W* I would like to point, that authorization (and authentication) MUST be performed only before action. What is the purpose of any authorization and exception raising when DB transaction, reading/writing to filesystem etc have been already done?

And using `before_action` has no problem with `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action` - there will be only one redirect - in exception handling before controller method call.

So, I recommend next code (updated *Jakob W's* sample):

```
class CabsController < ApplicationController
  #...
  before_action :authorize_user

  private
    #...
    def authorize_user
      if !((current_user.has_role? :admin, @operator) || (current_user.has_role? :super_admin))
        raise CanCan::AccessDenied
      end
    end
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :not_authorized

  #other stuff      

  private
  def not_authorized
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path), alert: "Unauthorized Access"
  end
end
```

Could I recommend another authorization gem? I think this one is flexible and easy to use - pundit (https://github.com/elabs/pundit). Page on github has some useful tips on authorization.